# Hi Does anyone have an example of uploading a video file to Amazon S3 using swift?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a video file to Amazon S3.
Please send an example using Swift
Thanks

Comment: [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725160/upload-file-from-ios-to-amazon-s3) is in objective-c but it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download this framework: [AFAmazonS3Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Manager)

Then add a bridge header to your code [this way](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-an-objective-c-bridging-header/)

Now just use this framework from Swift, it'll be very simple with Xcode auto-complete, something like this:

```
var s3Manager : AFAmazonS3Manager = AFAmazonS3Manager(
        initWithAccessKeyID: "your access key", secret: "your secret key");
s3Manager.requestSerializer.region = AFAmazonS3USWest1Region;
s3Manager.requestSerializer.bucket = "my-bucket-name";
s3Manager.postObjectWithFile(..read the docs..);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a start. I am following Amazon instructions. I would like so more input.

Answer (score 0):

It's all here:
Including the way to install the SDK (there are links to all the requirements)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html